# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly when using resources in 2 C# projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

I am currently working with 2 C# projects inside one VS 2017 solution. One project contains all the business logic and the other simply the UI. The UI, of course, references the Core project.

The Core solution uses RestSharp package on it's code, so I installed it using NuGet. When I run the solution and I reach the part of the code where RestSharp is used, the following exception is thrown: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'RestSharp'".

The problem gets solved if I also install 'RestSharp' package inside the UI project. But, I am trying to avoid that as the UI does not need to use that package.

Is there a way to avoid that? Regards

Comment: Well, at some point, your program needs to load the RestSharp assembly. That you fixed the program by including the RestSharp package with your UI project leads me to two assumptions: 1) Your UI project is the project generating the exe, and 2) when building the solution, your build process fails to copy/deploy the RestSharp assembly into the build directory of the exe. Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `Copy Local` is set to true for the `RestSharp` reference. When it is set the `RestSharp` dll will be copied along with the Core dll.

[image: Reference properties]